# What is wrong with my attempt to get the length of an array?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

A script has the following:

```
#/bin/bash
path_elements=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" " ")
echo ${#path_elements[*]}
```

My PATH variable contains several directories. However, when run, the output returns:

> 1

Why isn't this returning the number of directories in $PATH? What is needed to fix this?

Comment: If one wanted to be snarky, one could answer "nothing; you're getting the array's length correctly". Though `[*]` rather than `[@]` isn't necessarily a best practice stylistically -- in the cases where the two _do_ have semantic differences, the latter is almost always preferable.

Comment: Bash array support is weird; allowing a regular parameter to be treated as an array of length 1 is just one oddity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just reading into a single string with spaces in place of colons (and literal tab characters replaced with spaces, and glob expressions expanded, and various other behaviors you probably don't want); thus, when you ask how many strings exist in the array `path_elements`, you get the answer 1, because there's only one string (not an array at all).

---

Now, **this** is an array, and a best-practices way to read into it:

```
# This is the best-practices approach.
IFS=: read -r -a path_elements <<<"$PATH"
echo "${#path_elements[@]}"
```

...and this is an incorrect, buggy way to read into an array (that does, at least, create an array -- but doesn't handle directory names with spaces correctly, incorrectly expands globs, and causes a bunch of problems):

```
# This is a buggy antipattern that does, at least, create an array
path_elements=( $(tr ':' ' ' <<<"$PATH") )
echo "${#path_elements[@]}"
```

---

See [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for more on correct use of arrays.